# AngularJS convert JSON string to JSON object in filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am working on a defect where I am getting numeric data as a JSON Object but in view its auto converting to string. As a result I am unable to sort it.

For example,

```
data = [
{
  num : "1"
},

{
  num : "2"
},
{
  num : "3"
},

{
  num : "10"
},
{
  num : "12"
},

{
  num : "22"
}
]
```

So when I sort this with orderBy:num, its giving me below output

1
10
12
2
22
3

Because of Angular convert it as a string but I want in proper format. Please help!!

Comment: this should work. minimal change in code. `orderBy:+num`

Answer (score 0):

Two Solutions :

1. Remove quotes from the values inside the JSON object.
2. Convert each value to integer or float.

```html
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (d) {
        d.age = parseFloat(d.age);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom sorting function to convert the text to integer, then use that in the view for sorting. Like this:

```
<!-- in the view -->
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:byNum">

// in the controller
$scope.byNum = function(item) {
               return +item.num;
};
```

I would advice you to have a look at as why the JSON data is converted to text from numbers. This is not something that should happen in the view.